# Custom exception handler for status NotFound

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I want to implement custom exception handler for status NotFoundException for Spring Boot:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ AccessDeniedException.class, NotFoundException.class })
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> accessDeniedExceptionHandler(final AccessDeniedException ex) {
    ......
}
```

I can't find what is the proper import for `NotFoundException` Do you know what exception what is the proper import for that case?

Answer (score 1):

Either add an exception handler for a `NoHandlerFoundException`:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDto> handle(NoHandlerFoundException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Or have your controller advice extend [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api#status_400) and override the [`handleNoHandlerFoundException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#handleNoHandlerFoundException-org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException-org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest-) method.

By the way, your code snippet declares a handler for two different exceptions while the method parameter `final AccessDeniedException ex` explicitly expects an exception of type `AccessDeniedException`. I would suggest either declaring multiple handler methods or generalize the paramater to an `Exception` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Michiel on, method parameter(AccessDeniedException ex) should be parent class of below classes:

1. AccessDeniedException
2. NotFoundException

try this

```
@ExceptionHandler({ AccessDeniedException.class, NotFoundException.class })
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> accessDeniedExceptionHandler(final **Exception** ex) {
    ......
}
```

i have used @ControllerAdvice like

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler({BadRequestException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class, MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleBadRequestException(Exception exception, WebRequest request) {
        String message = StringUtils.isEmpty(exception.getMessage()) ? properties.getGeneralMessages().get("fail") : exception.getMessage();
        if (message.contains(";"))
            message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf(";"));
        return getResponseEntity(message, null);
    }
}
```